# Android WiFi AP doesn't send broadcast UDP when no STA in BSS

Tags: android, networking, udp, wifi, broadcast

I want to receive UDP packets from an Android WiFi AP (Access Point). I plan to receive broadcast packets with libpcap, so I do not need to associate STA (Associated Station) in network, to save time.

I wrote an Android app sending UDP packets to 192.168.43.255, and generally it works - I can receive the packets on STA, after it is registered in BSS. The problem is that the AP does **not**  send UDP packets when **no** STA is registered in BSS. From app point of view, the packets are being sent via socket w/o any errors/exceptions, but they are not detected with wireshark sniffer (being run on a not-associated PC, scanning AP channel). When I connect to the AP (from another Android phone), the UDP packets **does appear** in wireshark log.

From the log I see that UDP packets appear after STA receives 802.11 frame "Association Response" from AP. As soon as the STA detaches from BSS with frame "Deauthentication", the UDP packets are not sent to air (but the Android app still sends them without any errors).

I tried to send UDP packet via raw socket (as a native NDK app, found a sample on inet), with the same (negative) result.

I guess that Android WiFi code is optimized to not send UDP packets when there is no STAs in BSS. I would like to disable this 'optimization', is it possible? Is it the same in Linux AP, or it's Android-specific feature? I use TI dev board AM335x Starter Kit, and I'm building Android ROM from source code, so I can change almost everything, just I do not know where it is )) Any ideas are appreciated.

I probably could try to send my data not via UDP packet, but via a customized 802.11 frame, just UDP seemed easier for me, and it works via standard Android Java API. For 802.11 frames approach I will need to work via NDK, probably jNetpcap (java libpcap wrapper ported to Android), so it it looks not so easy for me.

I must say I'm not very good in this area (WiFi networking), so I may be asking something dump...

About my use case - I need to collect data via WiFi from a fast moving object (car), this is why I think that it would be good to send data in single WiFi frame without STA association procedure. I would like to broadcast the data without the limitation to have at least one STA in BSS.

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: just a wild guess, maybe totally unrelated (since its for the receiving side) but maybe its a good hint: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.MulticastLock.html

Comment: I saw that before posting the question. I didn't experiment with WifiManager.MulticastLock because UDP packets are sent OK without acquiring the lock. Well, I would need to use the lock, but for other reason (to prevent WiFi from going to sleep mode), but I do not think it is related to the question.

Comment: Just to wrap things up - I haven't found the cause for this behavior. My solution was to send data directly via WiFi driver, in 802.11 frames. Since I'm building Android ROM myself, I modified hostapd code to send new frames via ctrl interface, now I'm testing it via hostapd_cli, and then I plan to use it via NDK wrapper.

Comment: Another rationale about sending 802.11 frames directly, was that I noticed that UDP packets (at least broadcast ones which I used) were delayed, I mean that the hotspot didn't send them immediately, but with delay (2-3 seconds), sending several packets at one, though the app is sending them continuously, per each second. I saw the same complains here at SO